# Rendering a Height Map with OpenGL 2.1

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I am using OpenGL 2.1 to render a replica of popular hill by my university. I have a .bmp greyscale image of the hill in question, but have not figured out the code to correctly load and render the height map. I am required to use OpenGL 2.1.

Comment: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ has a limited 24-bit .bmp loader that you might find useful. The tutorial is mainly for OpenGL 3.3, but there's also code for the OpenGL 2.1 port. The tutorial uses C++ and modern OpenGL with VBOs. I have been able to create a heightmap using OpenGL 2.1 based on the code of the tutorial, so I can recommend it. http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/download/

Answer (score 4):

Here is the algorithm you can follow :

**1)** Read your bmp file into an array

**2)** Decide a formula that change your grayscale values[0,255] to height

**3)** Imagine each pixel is your vertex (x,z coordinates is u,v coords grayscale value is your y coordinate)

**4)** Define dX,dY and draw your array by triangles or rectangles

Note: If you know how to use glsl, you can give the same effect by displacement mapping.